# Is it supported to have nested menus in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Within Navabar is it possible to have a dropdown menu within another dropdown menu using Bootstrap 5.

I tried amending my code to add *dropdownBrowseMenuId* to *dropdownHelpMenuId* but it didnt like it. The help doesnt mention dropdowns within dropdowns so if it isnt supported I will not try to use it, but seems quite it would be quite a common requirement

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a href="#" id="dropdownHelpMenuId" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
      Help
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownHelpMenuId">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="dropdownBrowseMenuId" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
              Browse
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownBrowseMenuId">
              <a href="/albums.start?cid=0$albums&amp;title=Albums" class="dropdown-item">
                  Albums
              </a>
              <a href="/albumartists.start?cid=0$=Album_Artists&amp;title=Album Artists" class="dropdown-item">
                  Album Artists
              </a>
              <a href="/topcontainer.start?cid=0$=Overall_work&amp;title=Works" class="dropdown-item">
                  Works
              </a>
              <a href="/tracks.start?cid=0$items&amp;title=Tracks" class="dropdown-item">
                  Tracks
              </a>
              <a href="/folders.start?cid=0$folders&amp;title=Folders" class="dropdown-item">
                  Folders
              </a>
          </div>
      </li>
      <a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/help/help.html" class="dropdown-item">
          Help
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.jthink.net/songkong/help.pdf" class="dropdown-item">
          Pdf
      </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the clean way to implement Bootstrap 5 multi-level dropdown vertical navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913249/what-is-the-clean-way-to-implement-bootstrap-5-multi-level-dropdown-vertical-nav)

Comment: I think so, sounds like not intended to be done so unless you really want to do it my pragmatic view is to not use nested menus.

Comment: Can you tell me the structure of the menu?  what goes under what and I'll get you the code done.