# BS 5.0.2 - prevent default behavior of dropdowns - worked in BS4, but not in BS5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In BS4 I was able to do something similar to the following (in jquery though) to prevent dropdowns based on a condition met.  In 5.0.2 this doesn't seem to do anything and the dropdowns still show/hide as normal.  Does it not respect stopPropagation() and preventDefault() now or is there a different way this needs to be handled now?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown [data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').forEach(function(dd) {
    dd.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        if( *some condition met* ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }       
    });
});
```

Before someone asks... yes, my condition is being met and that is not the issue here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73249734/7186739

Answer (score 0):

### Revised answer based on the OP’s jsfiddle example

The `preventDefault()` for your BS4 version in response to a click wasn’t preventing Bootstrap’s dropdown, but rather it was preventing [Dallaslu’s  multi-level dropdown](https://github.com/dallaslu/bootstrap-4-multi-level-dropdown) – (Dallaslu’s code triggers the dropdown toggle).

Dallaslu does have a [Bootstrap 5 multi-level dropdown](https://github.com/dallaslu/bootstrap-5-multi-level-dropdown), which works with the menu from your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8n70ozt2/) after updating the code to use `data-bs-` and `dropend` instead of `dropright`.

```js
(function($bs) {
    const CLASS_NAME = 'has-child-dropdown-show';
    $bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function(_orginal) {
        return function() {
            document.querySelectorAll('.' + CLASS_NAME).forEach(function(e) {
                e.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
            });
            let dd = this._element.closest('.dropdown').parentNode.closest('.dropdown');
            for (; dd && dd !== document; dd = dd.parentNode.closest('.dropdown')) {
                dd.classList.add(CLASS_NAME);
            }
            return _orginal.call(this);
        }
    }($bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle);

    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
        dd.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
            if (this.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME)) {
                this.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.clickEvent && e.clickEvent.composedPath().some(el => el.classList && el.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle'))) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            e.stopPropagation(); // do not need pop in multi level mode
        });
    });

    // for hover
    function getDropdown(element) {
        return $bs.Dropdown.getInstance(element) || new $bs.Dropdown(element);
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-hover, .dropdown-hover-all .dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
        dd.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
            let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
            if (!toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
                getDropdown(toggle).toggle();
            }
        });
        dd.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
            let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
            if (toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
                getDropdown(toggle).toggle();
            }
        });
    });
})(bootstrap);
```

```css
/* ============  MOBILE VERSION OF THE HEADER NAV  ============ */

/* ============  HEADER AND LOGO  ============ */
#header {
    background-color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*logo*/
#header .navbar-brand {
    margin: auto;
    padding: .5625rem 1.625rem .5625rem 0;
    /*this centers the logo correctly as it is the width of the toggler*/
}

/*bottom spacing for entire dropdown menu*/
#header .navbar-nav {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* ============  SPECIAL MENU STUFF  ============ */
/*navbar check for jquery*/
#navbar-check {
    display: none;
}

/*smart header hide/show*/
.navbar-showhide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}

.navbar-showhide.scrolled-down {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.navbar-showhide.scrolled-up {
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#header .dropdown-menu.megaFull,
#header .dropdown-menu.megaLg {
    padding: .5rem 2rem 0;
}

#header .dropdown-menu.megaSub {
    padding: .5rem 3rem 0;
}

#header .dropdown-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    font-size: .9375rem;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem;
}

/* ============  MENU  ============ */
/*top links container*/
#header .nav-item {
    border-radius: .3rem;
}

/*top links*/
#header .nav-link,
#header .nav-link:focus {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    color: gray;
}

#header .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

/*top dropdown link solid color when open*/
#header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
    color: #fff;
}

/*dropdown arrows - remove bootstrap default*/
#header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:after {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*add custom dropdown arrows*/
#header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded=false]:after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content: '\f107';
    /*fal fa-angle-down*/
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: .5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

#header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded=true]:after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content: '\f106';
    /*fal fa-angle-up*/
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: .5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*dropdown box*/
#header .dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

/*dropdown box links inside*/
#header .dropdown-item {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: .9375rem;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: .25rem 2rem;
}

#header .dropdown-item:active,
#header .dropdown-item:focus,
#header .dropdown-item:hover,
#header .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
    /*this keeps the open dropdown link solid*/
    background-color: transparent;
}

#header .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

/*two levels*/
#header .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    padding: .25rem 3rem;
}

/*three levels*/
#header .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    padding: .25rem 4rem;
}

/*right side nav buttons*/
#header .ml-lg-auto .nav-item+.nav-item {
    margin-top: .25rem;
}

#header .ml-lg-auto .nav-link,
#header .ml-lg-auto .nav-link:active,
#header .ml-lg-auto .nav-link:focus,
#header .ml-lg-auto .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/*blue dropdown*/
#header .dropBlue {
    background-color: #347fc0;
}

/*green dropdown*/
#header .dropGreen {
    background-color: #4fab4f;
}

/*form stuff*/
#header .dropForm .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0 1.5rem 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}

#header .dropForm .dropdown-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem;
}

/*remember me*/
#header .custom-control-label {
    font-size: .9375rem;
}

#header .custom-checkbox .custom-control-label::before {
    border: 0;
}

/*in misc so it works on all pages*/

.custom-control-label::after {
    top: .2rem;
}

#header .custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: none;
}

#header .custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#header .custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: darken(#347fc0, 10%);
}

/*the toggler*/
#header .navbar-toggler {
    font-size: 1.750rem;
    /*makes a 26px (with padding) wide fontawesome icon*/
}

#header .navbar-toggler,
#header .navbar-toggler.collapsed:hover {
    color: #4fab4f;
}

/*when menu is closed and not hovered*/
#header .navbar-toggler.collapsed {
    color: #fff;
}


/* ============  DESKTOP VERSION OF THE HEADER NAV  ============ */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

    /* ============  HEADER AND LOGO  ============ */
    /*bottom spacing for entire dropdown menu*/
    #header .navbar-nav {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    /* ============  SPECIAL MENU STUFF  ============ */
    /*navbar check for jquery*/
    #navbar-check {
        display: block;
    }

    /*smart header hide/show*/
    .navbar-showhide.scrolled-down .dropdown-menu {
        opacity: 0 !important;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    #header .hasmegaFull {
        position: static !important;
    }

    #header .megaFull {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #header .megaSub {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    #header .dropdown-menu.megaFull,
    #header .dropdown-menu.megaSub,
    #header .dropdown-menu.megaLg {
        padding: 1rem;
        color: #bfe1ff;
    }

    #header .dropdown-title {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #fff;
    }

    /* ============  MENU  ============ */
    /*top links container*/
    #header .nav-item {
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    /*top links*/
    #header .nav-link,
    #header .nav-link:focus {
        padding: 1.125rem 1rem;
        color: #ccc;

        /*top link and dropdown menu transition should match*/
        /*transition: all .15s ease-in-out;*/
    }

    #header .nav-link:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4fab4f;
    }

    /*top link colors*/
    #header .dropBlue .nav-link,
    #header .dropBlue .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"],
    #header .dropBlue .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #347fc0 !important;
        border-color: #347fc0;
    }

    #header .dropGreen .nav-link,
    #header .dropGreen .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"],
    #header .dropGreen .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #4fab4f !important;
        border-color: #4fab4f;
    }

    /*top dropdown link solid color when open*/
    #header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4fab4f;
    }

    /*top links remove dropdown arrow*/
    #header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:after,
    #header .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        content: '';
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    /*add custom dropdown arrows for submenus*/
    #header .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        content: '\f105';
        /*fal fa-angle-right*/
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-left: .5rem;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    #header .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        content: '\f104';
        /*fal fa-angle-left*/
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-left: .5rem;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    /*dropdown*/
    #header .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #4fab4f;
        border-radius: .5rem;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        padding: .5rem .35rem;
        /*hover doesn't like this*/
        /*padding: .5rem 0;*/
        border-color: #4fab4f;
        border-top: 0;

        /*top link and dropdown menu transition should match*/
        /*  display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
        */
    }

    #header .show>.dropdown-menu {
        pointer-events: auto;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    #header .dropdown-menu li {
        position: relative;
    }

    #header .dropdown-menu li.hasmegaSub {
        position: relative;
    }

    /*dropdown box links inside regular*/
    #header .dropdown-item {
        color: #fff;
        padding: .3125rem .65rem;
        /*hover doesn't like this*/
        /*padding:.3125rem 1rem;*/
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        /*hover doesn't like this*/
        /*border-radius: 0;*/
    }

    #header .dropdown-item:active,
    /*#header .dropdown-item:focus,*/
    /*when on it leaves submenu link highlighted even when its submenu is closed*/
    #header .dropdown-item:hover,
    #header .dropdown .dropdown .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: lighten(#4fab4f, 7%);
    }

    /*multi level*/
    #header .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
        border-radius: .5rem;
        border: 1px solid darken(#4fab4f, 5%);
        top: calc(-.5rem - 1px);
        /*use calc when using border on these boxes - 1px covers border and .5rem is the top padding of the box*/
        /*left: calc(100% - .25rem);*/
        /*use to shift box a little to the left to overlap the previous*/
    }

    #header .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item,
    #header .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        padding: .3125rem .65rem;
        /*hover doesn't like this*/
        /*padding:.3125rem 1rem;*/
    }

    /*right side nav buttons*/
    #header .ml-lg-auto .nav-item+.nav-item {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    /*form stuff*/
    #header .dropForm .dropdown-menu {
        padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
        min-width: 17.875rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- BEGIN NAVBAR -->
    <nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-showhide dropdown-hover-all">
        <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img alt="test" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x42.png" height="42">
            </a>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-nav-scroll collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/test/">Regular Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="dropdown01" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">test no link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">one</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropend">
                                <a id="dropdown02" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test/" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">test with link</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">one</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown dropend">
                                        <a id="dropdown03" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test/" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">test with link</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">one</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">two</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">three</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">three</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="DD_megaSub" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">megaSub no link</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="DD_megaSub">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test/">test</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropend hasmegaSub">
                                <a id="DD_Mega4" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">test no link</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu megaSub" style="min-width:400px;" aria-labelledby="DD_Mega4">
                                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2">
                                        <div class="col pb-3 pb-sm-1 pb-lg-0">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-title">Title Menu One</h6>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col pb-1 pb-lg-0">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-title">Title Menu Two</h6>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a id="DD_Mega5" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">test no link</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu megaSub" style="min-width:400px;" aria-labelledby="DD_Mega5">
                                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2">
                                        <div class="col pb-3 pb-sm-1 pb-lg-0">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-title">Title Menu One</h6>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col pb-1 pb-lg-0">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-title">Title Menu Two</h6>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/test/">Submenu item</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropGreen"><a class="nav-link" href="/test/"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-pr"></i>regular link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown dropForm dropBlue">
                        <a id="DD_Login" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-pr"></i>form no link</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="DD_Login">
                            <form class="" role="form" method="post" action="http://example.com" target="_blank" autocomplete="off">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-title">Sign in to your account :</h6>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="signinUsername">Username</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="signinUsername" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="signinPassword">Password</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock-alt fa-fw"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input id="signinPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" name="remember">
                                    <label for="rememberMe" class="custom-control-label">Remember me?</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="signin" value="signin">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login Now</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->

</div>
<!-- END WRAPPER -->

<div id="navbar-check"></div>
```

I did not add the code from your BS4 version for handling touchscreens, but the snippet does show the menus working with hover.

*I did delete some of the menu items so the snippet would fit within Stackoverflow's size limit, but you should still be able to see the effect.*

Comment: This is definitely going in the right direction and thank you for the information.  The problem is I need to detect on `click` of the dropdown though.  I had a navbar setup that was multilevel and had links on the actual dropdown button itself.  The way I had it setup was on mobile those top links did nothing and just opened/closed the dropdown on click - it acted normal.  On desktop however the dropdowns were hoverable and you could click those top links and go to its link.  I'll see about setting up a fiddle for bs4 to show what I was doing.  Just trying to replicate that with bs5 now.

Comment: Best attempt at a fiddle with what I have for BS4.  Not the prettiest as some css and what not is missing, but shows the functionality working.  On small screens or touch devices the menu acts as normal just with multi level.  On large screen, and if not a touch device, the menu is hoverable and top menu links (if not #) are clickable and go to that link.  https://jsfiddle.net/8n70ozt2/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a **Late Answer**, But it may help someone out there!
Just Add This to Your Drop Down Button

```
data-bs-auto-close="false"
```

Source : [Official Bs Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior)