# Change background color in Bootstrap 5 multi level dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

anyone tried to changed the background color in multi-dropdown menu in bootstrap 5?
the original code is here https://bootstrap-menu.com/demos/multilevel.html

I want to change the background color in visited/active in multi level
the code below doesn't work

```
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, 
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:visited, 
.dropdown menu>.active>a:hover,  
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus { 
background-color: #222222!important;  
}
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZNI8.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73249734/7186739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bootstrap provide class to change dropdown menu color to dark by aading class ".dropdown-menu-dark" to dropdown-menu.

Hope that work for you