# Bootstrap 5 navbar responsive menu (dropdown part of it)

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, bootstrap-5

**Update:**
I managed to get desktop working. Just need to sort out mobile now.

The issue I am having is that the dropdown does not seem to work properly on mobile/desktop. And styling wise it is also fine/good as far as desktop/mobile goes. But the problem is functionality. I put in some placeholder links in the dropdown items (to see if that would make them appear) and this is not the case.

See the menu I am trying to get to work:

```
<nav id="navbar"class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="[[++url_images]]/logos/logo.jpg" alt="Your image is not loading"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active home" aria-current="page" href="https://www.google.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link about" href="https://www.google.com">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link contact" href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

- Also good to note: I can notice the classes shift between collapsed and collapsing and collapse show. But it does not show me any of the items.

Anyone have any idea why the menu is not showing up? Could this be that pre-existing CSS is interfering? (I already checked this to a limited extent as this was my first thought. But I couldn't get it to show the items by disabling some of the obvious ones.)
Now I would like to know whether or not I am missing something or I should just dig deeper in my custom CSS.

Also currently unable to get the sticky working on this again (but I managed this before on a simpler bootstrap menu so I will figure that one out. But if someone has some kind of magical piece of advice I am open to it.)

Also see attached my current compiled CSS:

```
/* MODULES ***************************************************************************************/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
/* PARTIALS **************************************************************************************/
.heading-xxl {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.heading-xl {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.heading-l {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-m {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-s {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-xs {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-l {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-m {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-s {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #07BE54;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #949BFF;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #FF965A;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #25DC71;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #125C30;
}

.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #07BE54;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #949BFF;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #FF965A;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #25DC71;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #125C30;
}

html {
  background-color: #1e4785;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  html {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.content {
  max-width: 70%;
}

.gradient-line-transparant {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(30, 71, 133), rgb(246, 255, 255), rgb(246, 255, 255), rgb(30, 71, 133));
}

.logo {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
}
.logo.center {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 28px;
}
.logo.chinook {
  align-self: center;
}

.photo {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .photo {
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: auto;
  }
}
.photo.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.photo.right {
  float: right;
}

div h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  div h1 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    align-self: center;
  }
}
div h2, div h3, div h4, div h5 {
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
div p {
  width: 100%;
}

p, li, ul, u, i {
  color: #1e4785;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a {
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
}

iframe.discord {
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  iframe {
    width: 225px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
}

.gametracker {
  float: right;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
}
a:hover {
  color: #f89830;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

/* ---------------------Sticky Nav Styling--------------------- */
/* Style the navbar */
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #1e4785;
  height: 10vh;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

.container {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0;
}
.container .menu {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

/* Navbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f89830;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 3vh;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 17px;
  }
}
#navbar a.home {
  margin-left: 5em;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a.home {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
#navbar a.about {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
#navbar a.contact {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e4785;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/*header closing tag*/
footer {
  text-align: center;
}
footerli, footer ul, footer u, footer i {
  color: #1e4785;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
footerh1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4, footer h5 {
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
}
footer a, footer a:hover {
  background-color: #1e4785;
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
  text-align: center;
}
footer p.col-md {
  background-color: #1e4785;
  color: #f7ffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section {
  align-self: center;
}
section div {
  text-align: center;
}
section div p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/*---------------Button styling below---------------*/
.button-primary {
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(100% 100% at 100% 0, #5adaff 0, #5468ff 100%);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(58, 65, 111, 0.5) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  height: 48px;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, transform 0.15s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: box-shadow, transform;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button-primary:focus {
  box-shadow: #3c4fe0 0 0 0 1.5px inset, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, #3c4fe0 0 -3px 0 inset;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 4px 8px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, #3c4fe0 0 -3px 0 inset;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.button-primary:active {
  box-shadow: #3c4fe0 0 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

body {
  background-color: #1e4785;
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .col-md {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

/* JAVASCRIPT *************************************************************************************/
/* FOUNDATION IMPORTS*/
html {
  visibility: visible;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In collapsed mode (mobile), the hamburguer icon functionality depends on the required javascript bundle to be included.
For instance, **https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js**.
Also, in your markup, you have a loose **a tag (anchor)**. Probably it came from copying from the examples in bootstrap's website.

See the following working code.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="navbar-brand" src="[[++url_images]]/logos/logo.jpg" alt="Your image is not loading"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-dark"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active home" aria-current="page" href="https://www.google.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link about" href="https://www.google.com">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link contact" href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your answer. 

1. Correct. the JS is loaded in on every relevant page through my footer and the bootstrapp css through header. 
2. I will check your version against mine, and let you know what I find!

Answer (score 0):

Since yesterday when I posted my update about having it work on desktop, I also managed to get it working on mobile.

I still have some styling issues (I want the menu to be in 1 place on all devices which currently is not happening yet as my hotfix involved a fixed position.)

But the actual problem I had (it not working int he first place) has been fixed by using the below code:

````
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="[[++url_images]]/logos/logo.jpg" alt="Your image is not loading"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-scroll">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active home" aria-current="page" href="https://www.google.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link about" href="https://www.google.com">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link contact" href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>-->
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>```

Compiled CSS (current version which makes it work not counting the styling issues that remain):

    /* VENDOR ****************************************************************************************/
/* MODULES ***************************************************************************************/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
/* PARTIALS **************************************************************************************/
.heading-xxl {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.heading-xl {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.heading-l {
  font-family: "Bree Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-m {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-s {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.heading-xs {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-l {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-m {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.font-text-s {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #07BE54;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #949BFF;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #FF965A;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #25DC71;
}
.heading-xxl.color-here {
  color: #125C30;
}

.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #07BE54;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #949BFF;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #FF965A;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #25DC71;
}
.heading-xl.color-here {
  color: #125C30;
}

html {
  background-color: #1e4785;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  html {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.content {
  max-width: 70%;
}

.gradient-line-transparant {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(30, 71, 133), rgb(246, 255, 255), rgb(246, 255, 255), rgb(30, 71, 133));
}

.logo {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
}
.logo.center {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo.chinook {
  align-self: center;
}

.photo {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .photo {
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: auto;
  }
}
.photo.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.photo.right {
  float: right;
}

div h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  div h1 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    align-self: center;
  }
}
div h2, div h3, div h4, div h5 {
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
div p {
  width: 100%;
}

p, li, ul, u, i {
  color: #1e4785;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

a {
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
}

iframe.discord {
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  iframe {
    width: 225px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
}

.gametracker {
  float: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
li.nav-item {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
}

a {
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
}
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

/*<---------------------Sticky Nav Styling--------------------->*/
/*<---------------------Dropdown menu styling--------------------->*/
.dropdown-menu.show {
  background-color: #1e4785;
}

/*<---------------------Style the navbar--------------------->*/
#navbar {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #1e4785;
  height: 10vh;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 102px;
  height: 102px;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .navbar-brand {
    width: 89px;
    height: 89px;
  }
}

.navbar-nav-scroll {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .navbar-nav-scroll {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 8.3em;
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
}

.container {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0;
}
.container .menu {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

/*<---------------------Navbar links--------------------->*/
#navbar a, #navbar.a:hover {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f89830;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: #1e4785;
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a, #navbar.a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a.home, #navbar.a:hover.home {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a.about, #navbar.a:hover.about {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}
@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  #navbar a.contact, #navbar.a:hover.contact {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e4785;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/*header closing tag*/
footer {
  text-align: center;
}
footerli, footer ul, footer u, footer i {
  color: #1e4785;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
footerh1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4, footer h5 {
  color: #1e4785;
  text-align: center;
}
footer a, footer a:hover {
  background-color: #1e4785;
  color: #f89830; /*Dutch Orange*/
  text-align: center;
}
footer p.col-md {
  background-color: #1e4785;
  color: #f7ffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section {
  align-self: center;
}
section div {
  text-align: center;
}
section div p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/*---------------Button styling below---------------*/
.button-primary {
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(100% 100% at 100% 0, #5adaff 0, #5468ff 100%);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(58, 65, 111, 0.5) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  height: 48px;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, transform 0.15s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: box-shadow, transform;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button-primary:focus {
  box-shadow: #3c4fe0 0 0 0 1.5px inset, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, #3c4fe0 0 -3px 0 inset;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 4px 8px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, #3c4fe0 0 -3px 0 inset;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.button-primary:active {
  box-shadow: #3c4fe0 0 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

body {
  background-color: #1e4785;
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  .col-md {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

/* JAVASCRIPT *************************************************************************************/
/* FOUNDATION IMPORTS*/
html {
  visibility: visible;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
````

Visualized:

[DesktopMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJwcO.png)

[Mobile Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJbrR.png)

Thanks to everyone who tried to help out in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I made a menu that can be used in Bootstrap 5. It supports multilevel dropdowns and columns on submenus. Dropdowns can be configured to expand right or left.

The font awesome css was included but it's only functionality is to add a hamburger icon.

This has been tested in Bootstrap 5.2.2.

**Github - Demo, screens and source (with CSS)**

https://github.com/lasseedsvik/Bootstrap-5-Mega-menu

**This is a completely "naked" menu with no additional CSS**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light pb-0 col-md-12">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-4 text-white" href="#">
            Bootstrap 5.2.2 Mega menu with multilevel dropdowns
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ms-4 shadow collapsed hamburger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbar-content">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl text-white"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="menu w-100">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active py-3 px-4" aria-current="page" href="#">Start</a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Multilevel dropdown -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-4 dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            data-bs-auto-close="outside">Multilevel</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mt-0 shadow">
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropstart">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Submenu
                                    Left</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropend">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                    data-bs-auto-close="outside">
                                    Submenu Right</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Yoghurt 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Yoghurt 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Yoghurt 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropend">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Hamsters</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hamster 1</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hamster 2</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hamster 3</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hamster 4</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Yoghurt 4</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- End Multilevel dropdown -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link py-3 px-4" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Mega menu -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-mega position-static">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle py-3 px-4" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            data-bs-auto-close="outside">Mega menu</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu shadow-lg col-lg-12 my-0">
                            <div class="mega-content px-4">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-4">
                                            <h5>Headline 1</h5>
                                            <div class="list-group">
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 1 link</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-4">
                                            <h5>Headline 2</h5>
                                            <div class="list-group">
                                                <a href="#">Col 2 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 2 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 2 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 2 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 2 link</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-4">
                                            <h5>Headline 3</h5>
                                            <div class="list-group">
                                                <a href="#">Col 3 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 3 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 3 link</a>
                                                <a href="#">Col 3 link</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!--End Mega menu -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
```

EDIT: Font awesome were only used in this case for the hamburger icon. It can ofcourse be removed and the hamburger menu could contain something else.